# High CPU usage running Symfony on PHP-CLI

Tags: php, windows-10

I have a Dell laptop with Intel i7 5th generation running Windows 10 x64 and PHP 5.6.17 x86 environment. When I run a fresh installation of Symfony 3.0 using php-cli:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

In few seconds CPU is loaded with 50% to 90% of their capacity, even if no access is requested to builtin php cli webserver. Any suggestions on how to drill down this issue?

Comment: Following a friend recomendation, I've tested again PHP 5.5.32 x85 and with PHP 7.0.3 x64 too, but the problem with high CPU loading persists.

Comment: can you disable internet access (unplug it, disable it, etc) and start the program again and report your results?

Comment: Go to Windows Task Manager using Ctrl+Shift+Esc, click Performance, and at the bottom, click Resource Monitor. Sort by Avg. CPU usage, and update the post with a screenshot of Resource Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But maybe it is not a problem. Reading here it describes that later versions of IIS with fast CGI try to optimize performance by automatically setting the max number of threads. So perhaps the massive cpu consumption is deliberate.

http://www.ksingla.net/2010/05/goodness-of-dynamic-maxinstances-in-fastcgi/

Answer (score 0):

### Can you confirm if both OS and PHP are 64 bit ?

It seems like you are running a 32 bit program on a 64 bit machine as per your info.

OS - Windows 10 x64
Language - PHP 5.6.17 x86

Also have you confirmed if you have used [thread-safe or non-thread saf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php)e version of PHP ? Generally Windows is compatible with thread-safe versions.

Also if you are on windows have you tried using 'Laragon' for PHP development? It supports all PHP frameworks, wordpress, laravel, symfony, etc along with being able to choose different versions of PHP, Apache, MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN which was really handy when I used windows.

Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php) discussing this topic.